# take each maximum value of a column and get information from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have two tables:

```
create table saller(
id_saller int IDENTITY  PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(50), 
branch varchar(10)
);

create table sale(
id_sale int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
amount float,
id_saller int,
CONSTRAINT fk_saller  FOREIGN KEY (id_saller)REFERENCES saller(id_saller)
);
```

i wanna get the biggest selling value of the amount for each branch 
and  get the name and id of the saller in charge for the biggest selling

i  tried this:

```
SELECT saller.name, saller.id_saller,maxv.branch, maxv.maxbranch
FROM saller 
INNER JOIN sale
 ON  saller.id_saller = sale.id_saller 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT saller.branch,saller.id_saller,MAX(sale.amount) AS maxbranch
    FROM  saller
    INNER JOIN sale 
        ON saller.id_saller = sale.id_saller 
    GROUP BY saller.branch,saller.id_saller
) AS maxv ON(sale.id_saller = maxv.id_saller)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it if you want to return exactly one row per branch even if you have ties

```
SELECT branch, id_saller, name, amount
  FROM
(
  SELECT r.branch, s.id_saller, r.name, s.amount, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.branch ORDER BY s.amount DESC) rnum
    FROM sale s JOIN saller r
      ON s.id_saller = r.id_saller
) q
 WHERE q.rnum = 1
```

or if you want the highest value with ties

```
SELECT branch, id_saller, name,  amount
  FROM
(
  SELECT r.branch, s.id_saller, r.name, s.amount, 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY r.branch ORDER BY s.amount DESC) rank
    FROM sale s JOIN saller r
      ON s.id_saller = r.id_saller
) q
 WHERE q.rank = 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3782c/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I don't understand the presence of branch, maybe a table that has not been mentionned. But to retrieve the seller id and name, you can try this;

```
SELECT saller.name, saller.id_saller 
FROM   saller 
INNER JOIN sale 
  ON  saller.id_saller = sale.id_saller 
WHERE sale.Amount = (Select Max(Amount) from sale)
```